# SSAS - Time Dimension Increasing Time Structure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, data-warehouse, dimensions, bids

I'm looking to increase the time dimension within a cube. Its currently set to Calendar end date 31/12/2012. Im looking to update it to end 31/12/2016. Currently using BIDS I've Increased the CalendarEndDate property in the dimension to '31/12/2016'. Saved it, processed the dimension, went to the browser and viewed the data but only shows up to Calendar 2012, no sign of 2013, 2014 ... etc.

Am I missing a step or is there anything else etc I must do before this will update?

Using SQL Server 2008R2. Dimension was set up prior to me taking ownership so unsure of how it was originally created but seems a pretty standard dimension with the source as the DSV.

Thanks

Comment: You should provide information on how you set up the time dimension, as well as your version of SQL Server (2005, 2008, 2008R2 or 2012)

Comment: Updated some details in the question @cairnz, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the developer used "Generate a Time Table on the Server" (first page of Dimension Wizard) option originally as you have CalendarEndDate available.  If that is the case, changing the CalendarEndDate, Processing the Dimension from Visual Studio (not SQL Server!) and browsing the Dimension should work.  By processing from dimension inside Visual Studio, you will force the new definition to be deployed.

If you are still having problems, try creating a new time dimension inside a test project and deploying to see if you get the same issue.  Compare the properties of both time dimensions to see if you can spot anything unusual.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Source section within properties shows the data source view while if a create one on our test project the source shows the date range and has (Time binding) at the end. While the current one is within 'TimeStructure' in the Generation Options section. <br>

Comment: Which would suggest the this wasnt created using the "Generate a Time Table on the Server" option.

Comment: If it has been generated based on your data, you will have to change the underlying data that feeds through your Data Source View to change the dimension range

Comment: Ok I've added a row to the Time table for jan 1 2013 and processed the cube. It now shows Calendar 2013 and drilling into that shows January, this would suggest that the data in this table is driving the dimension, correct? This would mean in order to update the dimension I'll have to do it through SQL via an update statement?  @Daryl Wenman-Bateson

Comment: You've got it.  The dimension is fed into your cube via the DSV, not generated by SSAS.

Comment: I've found some previous documentation, it looks like it was set up via the wizard through the "Generate a time table in the data source" option, shouldnt I be able to populate this method through SSAS? @Daryl Wenman-Bateson

Comment: You time table will have a source table that feeds the dimension through the dsv as opposed to being held on the server.  To change the data, you will need to adjust your source table, the same way you would for all other dsv based dimension tables

Comment: How do I know or find out where the source table is? Sorry new to SSAS etc. Thanks for your input so far :) @Daryl Wenman-Bateson

Comment: Go to the key of the dimension, drilldown into the KeyColumns -> TableName.FieldName -> Source.  Form there you will see the TableId and Column.  The TableId relates to the table in the Data Source View, whcih you can view the properties of to find the real table name.

Comment: Ok got that :) Found the table in the DSV the properties are: 'AllowChangesDuringGeneration' true, 'DataSource' DataWarehouse, Name 'Time', Schema 'dbo' and TableType 'Table'. Will this table have to be updated via an SQL update statement in order for the dates from 2013 onwards? Even though it seems likely that the table was generated from SSAS originally? Cheers

Comment: Updated via a script and worked well, just a bit more work than was hoping but got there, thanks for all your help @Daryl Wenman-Bateson